# Spring batch - How to write own values to header in output file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am developing a Spring Boot application.

I have an `input.csv` file to read and write values to DB, to do so I am using spring batch framework.
I am able to `read/insert` values to DB. Now I have created an `output.csv` file on which I have created a header with some column and setting a few column values extracted from `input.csv` file.

But for one column in `output.csv` file, I want to record the response i.e `00->success, 11->fail`

Ex: My header looks like  `{"S_NO;NAME;Dept;Salary;Rsp_code"}`
 In this, for the first 4 columns values, I am setting from `input.csv` file.

For column `rsp_code`, I want to set hardcoded values `00 and 11`.
if one row is successfully inserted to DB set `rsp_code` values like `00` otherwise `11`.

Is there a way to do this? MY header code as following:

```
ItemWriter<Valueholder> databaseCsvItemWriter() {
    FlatFileItemWriter<Valueholder> csvFileWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

    String exportFileHeader = "S_NO;NAME;Dept;Salary;Rsp_code";
    StringHeaderWriter headerWriter = new StringHeaderWriter(exportFileHeader);

    csvFileWriter.setHeaderCallback(headerWriter);

    String exportFilePath = "C:\\temp\\useroutput.csv";
    csvFileWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(exportFilePath));

    LineAggregator<Valueholder> lineAggregator = createStudentLineAggregator();
    csvFileWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);

    return csvFileWriter;
}

private LineAggregator<Valueholder> createStudentLineAggregator() {
    DelimitedLineAggregator<Valueholder> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    lineAggregator.setDelimiter(";");

    FieldExtractor<Valueholder> fieldExtractor = createStudentFieldExtractor();
    lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);

    return lineAggregator;
}

private FieldExtractor<Valueholder> createStudentFieldExtractor() {
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Valueholder> extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();

    extractor.setNames(new String[] {"id", "name", "dept", "salary"});

    return extractor;
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do header. what you want is to record 00 for success and 11 for failure. It is the line mapping. Valueholder should have this field mapped accordingly.

Comment: valuholder does not have those two attributes. I got one solution for this I opened the response file and on job failure and success have set the values for rsp_code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Data transformation is a typical use case for an [item processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemProcessor). So you can use an item processor to do the mapping. The advantage of this approach is that you can:

- unit test the mapping in isolation
- re-use the item processor in another step/job if needed

Comment: Yeah I am already using the item processor. however this has nothing to do with processor.